# What to do if nixos stay blocked after Starting systemd

Tags: nix, nixos

I start nixos from wsl.
Sometime after the start, it get blocked
I get these lines and nothing happends after that

```
Copying /usr/share/applications
Copying /usr/share/icons
setting up /etc...
setting up /bin...
Starting systemd...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't answer why nixos is blocked but it solves the problem.

open a new terminal. And then enter that:

```
 wsl --shutdown
```

and

```
 wsl
```

repeat as long as necessary

Answer (score 1):

I tried the solution of Pierre-Olivier Gendraud about 3 times with no success and then tried stopping and starting again via the "WSL Tray Monitor" windows app https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/wsl-tray-monitor/9P781RW2VM6G
NixOS then started up perfectly.

I can't say if the app did anything different than what Pierre-Olivier suggested but it may be worth a try (and the app is quite nice anyway and stays out of the way in the system tray until you need it).

Comment: It works. Any idea how?